# Start Skype in background

Tags: startup, skype, desktop-background, startup-applications

I would like to start Skype in the background in the startup.
I installed Skype with Software included in Gnome 16.04.

I succeed to add it to the startup but I don't know how to avoid to have the windows opened. I just want to keep it running in the background.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So you want to start Skype minimised, or in the system tray (which?) with no visible window (and no splash screen presumably?)? Which version of Skype is it? Are you still running Gnome (which version).

Comment: I want to have the little icon on the top bar so I don't what does that.
Whatever the method if it works.
My version is: GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to start skype in background go to `tools->settings` and toggle **on** `Launch Skype in the background` (the default is **off**).

And if you want icons in the top bar you may install gnome extension [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) which moves all tray icons (bottom left of Gnome Shell) to the top panel.

Comment: For current Skype 8.1 under Ubuntu-MATE 16.04, this option sadly takes no effect…